# minecraft- how to stop the voices that sing underwater?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing minecraft java edition 1.16.3. I know there are some "ambient noises" which you can disable but it seems it doesn't affect on these voices that sing underwater.

I am not playing on a server. i have no data packs. it is me, my pc and my world. it really become scary when I'm working under water. i needed clay to trade with villagers and.. dang it. i jumped out of water.

so is there any way to disable them?

Comment: Can you attach a clip of it?

Comment: @randomuser922 i will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the sound of it with a resourcepack.  You could change it to an empty sound file and that would get rid of it.  To do this you have to know which sound it is in Minecraft.  To change it you have to name a sound file the same as the sound in the game.  To remove it, make a empty .ogg file and name it the same as the sound you want to remove.  Below is a video on changing sounds in minecraft.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to get rid of the sounds that Minecraft NPC's make sadly. But if you really want to do it while you are underwater you could just mute Minecraft or your computer. But I would not recommend that you do this unless you dislike the sound that much. And that is because if you do that you might not here something important.

Comment: You can just make a texture pack that does it

Answer (score 1):

Try [Vanilla Tweaks](https://vanillatweaks.net/picker/resource-packs/). It offers an option which lets you remove cave sounds, under the Peace and Quiet section. I think this might be what you're referring to.